# grails field plugin: the "blank" error is not handled the same way as others?

Tags: validation, grails, plugins, field

I'm using Grails's [fields plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/fields) for its shortness regarding writing forms.

I don't have understood well its way of managing validation errors, though.

If the domain class as a "blank" constraint, the plugins displays a nice arrowed pop-up message "please fill in this field"  close to the corresponding property/field, even if no explicit error management code has been written in the controller or even in the form.

When I look in `messages.properties`, the `default.blank.message` is `"Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be blank"`, so I don't understand where the message given by this plugin come from.

Moreover, if I try another constraint like `"minSize:2"` for example, the error is not shown in the form as for the "blank" one, unless I handle and show it the regular way (code in both controller and view).

So, my questions are: in the field plugin

1. why is the "blank" validation different of other errors ?
2. how can I re-use the nice error pop-up for all errors ?
3. where is the javascript code for this pop-up ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This popup is the result of using the HTML5's attribute `required` for client-side validation, it does not need any JavaScript -- [see examples here](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2012/03/13/html5-form-validation.aspx).

Any html `input` field you use the attribute `required` will get that popup:

```
<input type="text" name="fieldName" required />
```